# Firebase cloud function not triggered

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to write a function that deletes a user from the firebase authuntication.
Here is the function:

```
//Delete user from authuntication and from database
export const deleteUser = 
  //firest make sure user is connected and active
  functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>{
    const userId: string = data.userId;
    UserHelpers.validateConnectedAndActive(context);
    if (!userId) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'invalid-argument',
        'Invalid parameters'
      );
    }
    //delete from firebase authuntication
    admin.auth().deleteUser(userId);
  })
```

And here is the call to the function from an angular service:

```
  public deleteUser(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.fns.httpsCallable('deleteUser')({userId});
  }
```

When I run the emulator and inspect the functions logs, i can see my function is initialized, but when I call it - there is no log indicating the function was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to try exports.deleteUser = () => { // your code } instead of what you are doing.